# Axis text offset in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

A short and quick question, is there a way to offset the text in the axis (not the title text)[image], as I use rather a large x-axis (aligned at an angle of 90) some of the text goes behind the plot...

here is the axis part of my code:::

```
add_legend("fill", title = "Score") %>%
  add_axis("x", orient = 'top', title = "Sample",title_offset=50,properties=axis_props(labels = list(angle=-90, fontSize=6))) %>%
  add_axis("y", orient = 'right', title = "Class")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you need to use the `tick_padding` argument for this. I provide an example as I cannot reproduce your plot.

Without an offset:

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>% layer_points()
```

[image]

And this is with the tick_padding (the offset is measured in pixels):

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>% layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", tick_padding=20)
```

[image]